# RatingBar incorrectly selected

Tags: android, ratingbar

```
<LinearLayout>
    ...
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
        android:id="@+id/starRatingBar"
        style="@style/yellowStarRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="0"
        android:stepSize="1" />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the right half of the , the next  is also selected. Do any of you know what is going on?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you set a `layout_weight`, this supersedes the `numStars` attribute.

```
  <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/starRatingBar"
                style="@style/yellowStarRatingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="0"
                android:stepSize="1" />
```

Comment: The purpose is to allow the user to manually select the rating.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I think the weight is interrupting the Ratingbar

Comment: weight=0.5 because there are other elements

Comment: I try to help you man. I found this article. Probably it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584058/android-ratingbar-not-visible-becomes-visible-only-on-touching